# finding the value in 2D array by inputting address

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to get the String right after the position i input, but it is not working and i can not identify why.
This is my code.

```
import java.util.*;
public class LabTest1_Mardi {
public static void main (String [] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    String myArray [][] = { {"a","b"}, {"c","d"}, {"e","f"}, {"g","h"}};

    //Getting row and cols
    int rows = myArray.length;
    int cols = myArray[0].length;
    System.out.println("Rows = "+rows+" Cols = "+cols);

    for (int x=0;x<rows;x++){
        for (int y =0;y<cols;y++){
            System.out.println("array "+x+" " + y + " : = "+myArray[x][y]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Enter Possition row : ");
    int posR = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Possition col : ");
    int posC = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println(myArray[posR+1][posC+1]);



    input.close();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Did you remember to use the `Scanner` class? (i.e. `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);`

Comment: I need to see a lot more code to actually see what is wrong. There are a lot of things that could potentially be wrong based on this.

Comment: I provided the code please check and let me know.

Comment: You may want to use `posR-1` and `posC-1` instead, and also check for valid row and column numbers before accessing the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which position are you trying to get? For example, if you enter in 0,0 (a) do you want b (0,1) or c (1,0)? Right now it should return d (1,1) because both row and column are incremented.

Image your 2D array looks like this, 
      0 , 1 
0: a , b
1: c , d
2: e , f
3: g , h

Right now you're shifting both row and column, make sure that's exactly what you want to do. Also you'll get an error if the user enters a 1 as their input values.